# Warning: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead in /home/

Tags: php

I need help with this code:

```
$replacement = preg_replace('/([\x80-\xFF])/e', '"=" . 
                            strtoupper(dechex(ord("\1")))', $value);
```

I get this error:

> Warning: `preg_replace()`: The `/e` modifier is no longer supported, use `preg_replace_callback` instead

So I need to use `preg_replace_callback`... but I don't know how?

Comment: Well the error message is quite clear: you should use `preg_replace_callback`. [Check the manual for examples.](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback)

Comment: Please can someone give me please the good code. I always get orror wheni try to change it. Thanks so much

Comment: Maybe post code you tried and the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the code translates to `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$replacement = preg_replace_callback('/([\x80-\xFF])/', function ($ms) {
    return '='.strtoupper(dechex(ord($ms[0])));
}, $value);
```